# for as - meaning

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions, as, literature

An excerpt from *Pi: A Biography of the World's Most Mysterious Number*:

> Since Euler is the father of the symbol that has the title role of this book, we ought to take a glimpse into his interesting life history. Born in Basel, Switzerland, in 1707, he was initially taught mathematics by this father, who himself studied under the famous mathematician Jakob Bernoulli. This connection served him well, **for as** the father noticed his son's proclivity for the subject, he arranged for him to study with Jakob Bernoulli's son (also a famous mathematician) Johann Bernoulli.

How to understand the construction **for as**?

Comment: "This connection served him well, *for the father, as he noticed his son's proclivity for the subject,* arranged for him to study with Jakob Bernoulli's son (also a famous mathematician) Johann Bernoulli."

Comment: You might find it easier if you substitute ***because*** or ***since*** for ***for***, and ***when*** for ***as***, which would convey exactly the same meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For** and **as** in this sentence are two separate components.

**For** can be used as a conjunction meaning "because." So you could rewrite this as follows:

> This connection served him well, **because** as the father noticed his
>   son's proclivity for the subject, he arranged...

"as" here describes a process - the father noticed more and more his son's proclivity, which led him to arrange for him to study with the mathematician.